# Making request to LinkedIn API results in 401

Tags: php, linkedin-api, http-status-code-401

I am trying to make an `API` to à LinkedIn users profile using `PHP`.
I've successfully registered my application and I've noted my API and Secret Key as well as listing my redirect url.

The user starts on this page: `index.php`. This page contains a link to the linkedIn dialog box:

```
<a href="https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=<?php echo $api_key ?>&state=<?php echo $state ?>&redirect_uri=<?php echo $redirect_uri ?>">Apply Now</a>
```

When I click on this link I sign in to LinkedIn using my details and I am successfully redirected to `application_form.php`. From here I would now like to get the users profile details:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.linkedin.com/v1/people/~");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
var_dump($output);
```

However the above code results in this being output:

```
"401 Unknown authentication scheme"
```

After doing a bit of research I think it might be because I still have not acquired an access token at this point? Would anyone have any idea what I should do in order to fix this?

Comment: I don’t know if you have acquired an access token yet – but you are certainly not _using_ one in your cURL request.

Comment: @CBroe I do have an `access_token` I can see it in the url `code=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN`. I guess I'm unsure how I can use it in my cURL request.

Comment: They have a lot of PHP code samples in their documentation, so I’d suggest you go have a look there.

Comment: I've been looking there but the code the example they provide seems to be aquiring the token by by exchanging the authorization_code for it. I am trying to Generate Authorization Code by redirecting user to LinkedIn's authorization dialog which they do not provide an example of from what I can see....

Comment: Function `getAuthorizationCode` in the example on https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/code-samples does exactly that– build the login URL and redirect the user there …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who is reading this and would like to use the `LinkedIn Profile API` the solution to my problem was that I did not have a valid `Access Token` when I attempted to make the first request.

The first thing I did was create a link that would direct the user to `LinkedIn` authentication dialog box.

Next the user would then choose to approve or reject my applications  request to access their profile. Regardless of their choice they are redirected to my `redirect url`.

From here I now have an `access code` which I can use to request an `access token` and thus make api calls.

```
if (isset($_GET['error'])) {
    echo $_GET['error'] . ': ' . $_GET['error_description'];
} elseif (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    getAccessToken();
    //$user = fetch('GET', '/v1/people/~:(firstName,lastName)');//get name
    //$user = fetch('GET', '/v1/people/~:(phone-numbers)');//get phone numbers
    $user = fetch('GET', '/v1/people/~:(location:(name))');//get country
    var_dump($user);
}
```

The `getAccessToken()` method that I used based on the code on the LinkedIn Developers site

https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/code-samples

```
 function getAccessToken() {
    $params = array(
        'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
        'client_id' => 'MY API KEY',
        'client_secret' => 'MY SECRET KEY',
        'code' => $_GET['code'],
        'redirect_uri' => 'MY REDIRECT URL',
    );
    // Access Token request
    $url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken?' . http_build_query($params);
    // Tell streams to make a POST request
    $context = stream_context_create(
            array('http' =>
                array('method' => 'POST',
                )
            )
    );
    // Retrieve access token information
    $response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
    // Native PHP object, please
    $token = json_decode($response);
    // Store access token and expiration time
    $_SESSION['access_token'] = $token->access_token; // guard this! 
    $_SESSION['expires_in'] = $token->expires_in; // relative time (in seconds)
    $_SESSION['expires_at'] = time() + $_SESSION['expires_in']; // absolute time
    return true;
}
```

Then the `fetch()` method, also from LinkedIn API

```
function fetch($method, $resource, $body = '') {
    $opts = array(
        'http' => array(
            'method' => $method,
            'header' => "Authorization: Bearer " . 
            $_SESSION['access_token'] . "\r\n" . 
            "x-li-format: json\r\n"
        )
    );
    $url = 'https://api.linkedin.com' . $resource;
    if (count($params)) {
        $url .= '?' . http_build_query($params);
    }
    $context = stream_context_create($opts);
    $response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
    return json_decode($response);
}
```

By doing the above, I had no problem making requests to the `API`. In fairness to Cbroe who commented above. I was missing this information. If he/she would like to leave an answer I'll gladly accept but just incase I've included my solution for anyone who runs into the issue I had.