# Get Request php

Tags: php, get, linkedin-api

I am implementing the linkedin API uaing OAuth and I am on fourth step of this documentation: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2
My code is working perfectly till step 3 because I obtained the access_token from linked in.

I just want to make a GET request. The sample call in the documentation is given as:

```
GET /v1/people/~ HTTP/1.1
Host: api.linkedin.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
Authorization: Bearer AQXdSP_W41_UPs5ioT_t8HESyODB4FqbkJ8LrV_5mff4gPODzOYR
```

How do I implement it in PHP?  ANy help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If i understood you correctly, this will do: http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-get.php

Comment: Use `curl`. http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php but pre-made software already exists out there for this, so why re-invent the wheel?

Answer (score 0):

file_get_contents function will work in addition to curl.

```
e.g.
$response = file_get_contents('http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~ HTTP/1.1');

echo $response;
```

Comment: I can see that you have passed the URL inside the parenthesis, but where do I pass the other data like, Host, Connection and Authorization? As shown in my question?

Comment: @Frank. Host and connection are already there (api.linkedin.com and http://). Check http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Comment: This link helped me out solving my problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28073184/making-request-to-linkedin-api-results-in-401